# CSS Centre Text (in a list item grid)

Tags: html, css

I have some simple css, it makes a nice little three by three grid.  What I can't seem to do is centre the text (both vertically and horizontally).  Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/a735p/).

```
        #card {
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
        }

        #card ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #card li {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
            width: 99px;
            height: 99px;
        }​
```

I have tried vertical-align but to no avail.  do I need to span each list item?  I cant keep up with css!

Comment: There are some good solutions in the answers. But in general, vertical centering in CSS is not intuitive or easy to fix in a good way. Read this: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `line-height: 99px;` (vertical alignment) and `text-align: center;` (horizontal alignment) to the #card li, like so:

```
#card li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    width: 99px;
    height: 99px;
    line-height: 99px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/GjFAc/)

Comment: First answer and best explained +1

Comment: Cheers, though I could elaborate some more on it ;-)

Comment: Works a treat! if the text is too long however it overflows over itself. How could I fix that?

Comment: You could try wrapping the text inside a <div> with a normal line height (resetting that 99px) and a display: inline. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/crG7H/

Comment: Then, to prevent even that div from having text flowing out from it, you can add max-height: 99px; and overflow: hidden; to that div.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change HTML to separate lists I would [suggest](http://jsfiddle.net/a735p/12/)

If not, and you know that there will be only one row use `line-height`

If previous suggestions doesn't help, `span` it and make it `display: table-cell;`